# How to tell Django not to render static inside of string

Tags: jquery, django

I have some code in `jquery` function that i want to append:

```
elementToAppend="<img src=\"{% static 'st_forms/images/warning-icon.png' %}\" hspace=\"10\">"+message;
```

This is string, but `django` trying to render this static. How to tell django not to render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this tag can help:

**verbatim**
Stops the template engine from rendering the contents of this block tag.

A common use is to allow a Javascript template layer that collides with Django’s syntax. For example:

```
{% verbatim %}
    {{if dying}}Still alive.{{/if}}
{% endverbatim %}
```

in your case:

```
{% verbatim %}
elementToAppend="<img src=\"{% static 'st_forms/images/warning-icon.png' %}\" hspace=\"10\">"+message;
{% endverbatim %}
```

Comment: need to pass 8 minutes :). In a minut i will :D

Comment: sorry i didn't saw another problem :) now the static is never rendered. But i want to render after this element is appended. Is there way to do this? DOM is changed after append, but django not render...

Comment: @user2758618 you pass that string to template engine and dont want to render it, right? but later you want that string to render somehow? dont understand what you trying to achieve, describe more plz

Comment: when I click on some link, I want to show warning icon plus text. That warning icon is a static file on server and i get that file by rendering static. But i want to render that static after i click on link.. I click on link, than append img tag that contains static to p tag, and than show icon. When I append img to p i want to django now render statc contained in img tag

Comment: @user2758618 and why you dont want to render it? you need result of static tag work in js...

Comment: Oh yes you are right! :). But why django displays templateSyntaxError here: elementToAppend="<img src=\"{% static 'st_forms/images/warning-icon.png' %}\" hspace=\"10\">"+message;

Comment: @user2758618 did you have this in template: {% load static from staticfiles %} ? post error stack trace